# Why i'm getting empty view below progress bar in Recyclerview pagination?

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement infinitive RecyclerView and i have achieved that within adapter. I have set two view types of RecyclerView, one for showing items and one for showing loading bar at bottom.

Here is one fragment of code from adapter:

```
final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager();
        mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                lastVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();

                if (!isLoading && totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                    // End has been reached
                    // Do something
                    if (mOnLoadMoreListener != null) {
                        mOnLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
                    }
                    isLoading = true;
                }
            }
        });
```

And this is how i'm calling method from adapter for loading more data:

```
// Load more data when user reach bottom
        mAdapter.setOnLoadMoreListener(new OnLoadMoreListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore() {
                // add null , so the adapter will check view_type and show progress bar at bottom
                mUsers.add(null);
                mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mUsers.size() - 1);

                // Load data
                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // Remove loading item
                        mUsers.remove(mUsers.size() - 1);
                        mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(mUsers.size());

                        // Load data
                        int start = mUsers.size();
                        int end = start + 20;
                        for (int i = start + 1; i <= end; i++) {
                            User user = new User();
                            user.setName("User " + i);

                            mUsers.add(user);
                        }

                        mAdapter.setLoaded();
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, 2000);
            }
        });
```

So this is what is happening. Everything works with implementation of infinitive RecyclerView. Data is loaded at the end, but before data is loaded, i'm getting some empty view. Means that user can scroll below progress bar while it is loading new data.

This is output:

[image]

Comment: What's the expected result?

Comment: Well, i want that progress bar shows at the bottom and that user can't scroll below progress bar while progress bar is loading new data..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this because you didnt set `wrap_content` in your Progress item's `Xml`. If you check it and post your `Xml` i can take a look at.

Comment: I forgot to check that file. That was it.