# RecyclerView, CardView, "dead" space between cards

Tags: android, xamarin

I implemented A RecyclerView in which I display some CardViews from a list, but the problem Is that when displayed there is so much space between cards, the space is the same space the CardView has as height and only at the bottom of each card.

This is my code:

CardView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:padding="5dp">
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="245dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    cardview:cardElevation="4dp"
    cardview:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="8dp">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/ivProduct"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#333333"
            android:text="Photo Title"
            android:id="@+id/txtTipo"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#333333"
            android:text="Photo Title"
            android:id="@+id/txtdescripcion"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

RecyclerView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
  android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
  android:scrollbars="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

[image: 1]

[![2][2]][2]

[image]

Comment: Add a picture to show what's going on. Most likely you aren't using enough height compared to your `android:layout_height` and thus you get weird spacing between the two. You could just wrap the content instead.

Comment: I just put the image, in where should I wrap the content?

Comment: The problem looks like you are filling the whole parent in your `RecyclerView` which is then causing a full screen to only show one item. You should instead use `wrap_content`. I would suspect in the actual `RecyclerView` this should change. And in your parent layout of your card, you should use `match_parent` instead.

Comment: Please checkout this question : [why-im-getting-empty-view-below-progress-bar-in-recyclerview-pagination](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37929766/why-im-getting-empty-view-below-progress-bar-in-recyclerview-pagination)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your LinearLayout inside the RecyclerView is with a `fill_parent` height,so the height assume the screen height, just change for `wrap_content`.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"         <!--change in this line-->
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp">
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="245dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    cardview:cardElevation="4dp"
    cardview:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="8dp">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/ivProduct"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#333333"
            android:text="Photo Title"
            android:id="@+id/txtTipo"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#333333"
            android:text="Photo Title"
            android:id="@+id/txtdescripcion"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you take a look directly at our sample:

https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/android5.0/RecyclerViewer/RecyclerViewer

There's many ways you can approach this, but the overall issue is that you are giving the children inside the `RecyclerView` height enough to fill the whole screen. Thus you should only give them enough height to `wrap_content`.

https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/android5.0/RecyclerViewer/RecyclerViewer/Resources/layout/PhotoCardView.axml#L5

and

https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/android5.0/RecyclerViewer/RecyclerViewer/Resources/layout/PhotoCardView.axml#L8